# Cycling ex commands in a vim macro

Tags: vim

This is probably a dumb question but I figured I share my experience as well.

While recording a macro, I was trying to use ex commands I had done previously by cycling through them with the up arrow. My macro was breaking somewhere and I'm assuming it's because the macro is recording keystrokes and not necessarily the contents of what I execute?

If so, is there a way around this?

Comment: If you haven't already, you may find the command-line window helpful for navigating history. `:h q:` or `:h q/` will show you more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, macros are literal recordings of what you type, so you have to be a little careful. Completing Ex commands with <kbd>Tab</kbd> probably works better than recalling entire history items with <kbd>Up</kbd>.

You can view the contents of a recorded macro (e.g. for register q):

```
:new
:put q
```

You can then even edit the macro, and update it via `0"qy$` or

```
:let @q = getline('.')
```

Comment: There is `:reg q` for viewing. It highlights special characters as well.

Comment: And `0"qy$` as replacement for `getline('.')` thing in case somebody wants to edit register in buffer, but does not want to type that `setline` thing or end up having additional `<C-j>` at the end of the register (in case of `"qyy`). This command will modify yank and default registers though in addition to `q`.

Comment: That's already mentioned in my answer, but I appreciate the care you invest into making this more useful. Thanks for your many good contributions!

Comment: Sorry, did not notice this: block below is far more attractive.